# Workbook With VBA Project and Worksheets Copied From One Another Shows Wrong Cell Values When You Press "Calculate Now"

Tags: vba, user-defined-functions, worksheet

I have a template workbook made up of identical worksheets which have been copied from one another. I have about 10 functions in a VBA Project which I use on each worksheet. I've then saved the template as a macro-enabled workbook and filled it in. I've done this twice so I now have two workbooks, say workbookA.xlsm and workbookB.xlsm which have come directly from that template. Each worksheet has a lot of grouped columns, i.e. columns that can be hidden with the toggle of a + or - sign at the top of left hand side of the screen. I have the calculation mode set to Manual. I'm using Excel 2007.

One of my functions is called SUM_TOTAL (given below) which takes 2 ranges and a string, adding up items of the second range if the string is in the first range.

I'm getting issues with the calculation process, if I have it on automatic calculate or if I press "Calculate Now" then the active sheet will calculate OK but then many of the other identical sheets will give the same values as that active sheet where the function SUM_TOTAL is given. Some work and some don't which I assume is to do with the fact that not all cells get calculated each time. It suggests to me that the sheets aren't entirely independent, but I can't see any way in which they are linked.

I've written a macro which cycles through the worksheets and performs "Calculate Sheet", but I thought this is what "Calculate Now" does? I want to understand it as other people will end up using the model and I need to know it is robust.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as quickly as possible!

Many Thanks, S

```
Public Function SUM_TOTAL(amount_type As String, amount_type_column As Range, 
range_to_sum As  Range) As Single

Dim cell As Range

SUM_TOTAL = 0

    For Each cell In amount_type_column

        If cell.Value = amount_type Then

            SUM_TOTAL = SUM_TOTAL + Cells(cell.Row, range_to_sum.Column).Value

        End If

    Next cell

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a UDF function to update everytime even if the input arguments (amount_type, amount_type_column, range_to_sum ) does not change.

1. You can presss Ctrl +Alt + f9 to Full re-calculate all functions, or in vba 
   `Application.CalculateFull`  or even more powerful Crtl + Shift + Alt + F9/`Application.CalculateFullRebuild`
2. (Use with caution, this makes your function to re-calculate whenever there's a change in worksheet)
   You should make your function Volatile, by adding 
   `Application.Volatile` in `SUM_TOTAL` funciton in any of the line

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried them all but still had the problem of whenever a SUM_TOTAL function was calculated on a worksheet that wasn't the active worksheet (i.e. the one that you were on when you pressed "Calculate Now"), then it was still referencing from the active worksheet. The good news is that I've SOLVED THE PROBLEM: In SUM_TOTAL I referenced to     Cells(cell.Row, range_to_sum.Column).Value, which was always referring to the active worksheet and not the one that was being calculated, so I've changed it now to cell.Offset(0, (range_to_sum.Column - cell.Column)).Value